# Uncooked pot roast

Tags: food-safety

I purchased a big roast and accidentially left it out for 3+ hours from the refrigerator. It was still cool in the wrapped package. Is this okay or should I toss?

Answer (score 0):

From the food safety course - no. If it was frozen then you'd have to let it defrost refrigerated, but it's been sitting at the food temperature danger zone for 3 hours. It's questionable.